# Rename File using Java renameTo and characters like á - í - ñ

Tags: java, file-rename

When I run this code

```
String path = "E:";


File F = new File(path,"TEST.txt");

File FF = new File(path, "áéíóúñ.txt" );

F.renameTo(FF);
```

I get a file with this name: Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºÃ±.txt

Can I get the rigth name somehow?

I think my .txt file is saved in UTF-8 and It still does not work, i save it again anyway.              i used the syntax \uXXXX, but it doesnt work, anyway i have to read the name since a txt file, when i read the name, i can see name with characters like "áéñ.. (using scanner class)" but when used renameTo, it doesnt work.

Comment: Does it work when you use the syntax `\uXXXX` for the characters you want in the string?

Comment: It seems that you're using Windows encoding for your source files.  If you save it in `UTF-8` it should work.

Comment: I think my .txt file is saved in UTF-8 and It still does not work, i save it again anyway.

Comment: Would generally be better to use \uXXXX syntax, encoding is one of those things that just keeps breaking when you least expect it.